How to make it appear in its original position when view appears?
I created a textfield and wrote the code below to make the textfield appear right above the keyboard when the keyboard appears.
But the textfield appears from top to bottom
I hope it shows up right away
What should I do?
inputTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
inputTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
inputTextField.backgroundColor = .white
inputTextField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.bezel
inputTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center

view.addSubview(inputTextField)

registerKeyboardNotifications()

func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
    
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let textFieldOrigin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: keyboardSize.origin.y - inputTextField.frame.height)
        
        inputTextField.frame.origin = textFieldOrigin
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    inputTextField.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 5000)
    inputTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}


"make the textfield appear right above the keyboard when the keyboard appears" -- What do you really mean? Do you want your text field to be hidden and only shown when the keyboard is open? Or, is your textfield visible somewhere on the lower portion of the screen, and you want it moved up when the keyboard is opened?

@DonMag - I want the textfield to be visible when the keyboard is open.

But... should the textfield be hidden before the keyboard opens? Are you trying to do something like a chat / messaging app, where the textfield is visible at the bottom of the screen, and when you tap into it it slides up with the keyboard?

@DonMag - Thank you for answer Initially I want to hide the textfield I want to make the textfield visible only above the keyboard when the keyboard is visible.

So... how are you "showing the keyboard" if the textfield is hidden and the user cannot tap into it?

@DonMag - When clicking a button I use textField.becomeFirstResponder()

UI changes are automatically animated when the keyboard is being shown.
Add an observer for keyboardDidShowNotification -- set the hidden textfield's origin in willShow and then set .isHidden = false in didShow.
Here's an example:
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var inputTextField: UITextField!
    var showBtn: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        inputTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        inputTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        inputTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        inputTextField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.bezel
        inputTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center

        // start with text field hidden
        inputTextField.isHidden = true
        
        view.addSubview(inputTextField)
        
        var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        cfg.title = "Show"
        showBtn = UIButton(configuration: cfg, primaryAction: UIAction() { _ in
            if self.inputTextField.isFirstResponder {
                self.inputTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            } else {
                self.inputTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        })
        showBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(showBtn)
        showBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
        showBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true

        registerKeyboardNotifications()
        
    }
    
    func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
        // Register for keyboard notifications
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

        // also add a keyboardDidShowNotification observer
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            let textFieldOrigin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: keyboardSize.origin.y - inputTextField.frame.height)

            // set the hidden textfield's origin
            self.inputTextField.frame.origin = textFieldOrigin
        }
    }
    @objc func keyboardDidShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        // show the textfield
        self.inputTextField.isHidden = false
        // update the button title
        self.showBtn.configuration?.title = "Hide"
    }
    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        // hide the textfield
        inputTextField.isHidden = true
        // update the button title
        self.showBtn.configuration?.title = "Show"
    }
}

        

